# Show Admob Banner Ad only on game play screen but not main menu

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, admob, cocos2d-x

I am using `Cocos2d-x` and I would like to integrate `Admob`. This is easy as I can use their SDK and add it in XCode, etc etc. But, I don't want to show the banner for every screen of my game.

What I would like to do is only show the banner ad during gameplay, but not on the main menu, etc.

Is it possible to do this? Does `Cocos2d-x` provide some sort of a callback that I can hook into so that my `Objective-C` can know which screen the game is on, and can then show or hide the ad?

Comment: Try to implement in Appdelegate method and call that method where you want to show :)

Comment: Not sure I follow how that will solve my problem.

Comment: @DavidR is correct. implement it in AppDelegate, perhaps statically and then just call it when you want to show an ad.

Comment: @GameDeveloper Are you meaning in my `AppDelegate.cpp` file?

Comment: @GameDeveloper Can you give me a bit more help on how I can have the `AppDelegate.cpp` file interact with the `Objective-C` that would be needed to show the `Admob` ads?